# Activity Indicator in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, activity-indicator

Each OS has an activity indicator. OS X and iOS has a flower that lights up and fades each pedal in a circular pattern. Windows has a spinning blue disk thing. Android has a gray disk thing (I think it can be in a variety of other colors, too - IDK, I don't use Android much.)

What's the best way to use these icons in Tkinter? Is there some built in widget that provides this? Is there maybe a variable that I can point an Image widget at to get it to display this icon (and animate it?)

I know Tkinter provides a Progress Bar, which has an indeterminate mode. I don't want to use that - I need something that fits in a small square area, not a long rectangular area. The activity indicator as described in the first paragraph will be perfect.

Or is my best option going to be to just roll my own canvas animation?

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe this can help for MacOS https://gist.github.com/pudquick/f7cefd0d4320e0b648da

Comment: probably you will have to display image with `Canvas` or `Label` but you will have to make animation on your own (using `root.after`)

Comment: @NoelSegura - Huh. That relies on `AppKit`/`Cocoa`. Is there a way to mix widgets from `AppKit` with widgets from `Tkinter`? I was under the impression you couldn't.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, Appkit will spawn a new window, maybe there is a way to get the animation resources, but at that point I don't know how better is it compared to download a gif and making the animation yourself in canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough for what you trying to do. I would than create my own animation or download from the internet frame by frame which you want to display. Canvas are more for interactivity with the user thats why I am using a label for displaying the images...

```
import tkinter as tk

class Activity(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master = None, delay = 1000, cnf = {}, **kw):
        self._taskID = None
        self.delay = delay
        return super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)

    # starts the animation
    def start(self):
        self.after(0, self._loop)

    # calls its self after a specific <delay>
    def _loop(self):
        currentText = self["text"] + "."

        if currentText == "....":
            currentText = ""

        self["text"] = currentText

        self._taskID = self.after(self.delay, self._loop)

    # stopps the loop method calling its self
    def stop(self):
        self.after_cancel(self._taskID)
        # Depends if you want to destroy the widget after the loop has stopped
        self.destroy()


class AcitivityImage(Activity):
    def __init__(self, imagename, frames, filetype, master = None, delay = 1000, cnf = {}, **kw):
        self._frames = []
        self._index = 0
        for i in range(frames):
            self._frames.append(tk.PhotoImage(file = imagename+str(i)+'.'+str(filetype)))

        return super().__init__(master, delay, cnf, **kw)

    def _loop(self):
        self["image"] = self._frames[self._index]

        # add one to index if the index is less then the amount of frames
        self._index = (self._index + 1 )% len(self._frames)

        self._taskID = self.after(self.delay, self._loop)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

# create a activity image widget
#root.b = AcitivityImage("activity", 3, "png", root)
#root.b.pack()

# create the activity widget
root.a = Activity(root, 500, bg = "yellow")
root.a.pack()

# start the loop
root.a.start()
#root.b.start()

# stop the activity loop after 7 seconds
root.after(7000, root.a.stop)
#root.after(8000, root.b.stop)

root.mainloop().
```